# Grails - Customizing datasource configuration from a spring bean

Tags: spring, grails, configuration

I have a legacy grails app running grails v3.2.9. We are currently using properties files for setting the dataSource configuration.

We have an internal system that stores our configurations that is loaded as a spring bean. I need to use this to hook it into our configuration system for compliance reasons. Is there any way to configure the dataSource from these at startup?

Comment: You consider Grails 3.2.9 legacy? Wish I had that luxury ;-)